# How to queue 3 dependent functions using threads and queues

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have 3 functions which I need to run. Each function generates a certain output that the next function depends on. So basically, once the first one finishes only then I can proceed to the second one, but once the second one runs, I can start running the first one again to generate the next batch of data - so I want to run them both at the same time, but I can't run the second one before I finish the first one, and the third one before I finish the second one. But I can run the first and second while the third is running. How can I implement that using threading in python? I understand the basics behind threading, but I don't know how to create the queue for that purpose.

This is an example of what I need to do:

```
# This is what will usually happen without threading. How can I implement the
# same thing but with threading? Keep in mind that foo() 1, 2 and 3
# take some amount of time. And foo2() may finish before foo() finished
# generating data, so I can't run foo2() until I have the data from foo()

# foo generates the data for foo2
data = foo()
# foo2 generates data for foo3
data2 = foo2(data)
# foo3 does something with data2 and the data is no longer used
foo3(data2)
```

Comment: Why are threading in the first place?

Comment: Because I want to generate the next batch of data with foo while foo2 and foo3 are running, as they take time, that is valuable. The same thing with foo2, I can already generate data for foo3 while foo3 is running.

Comment: It won't speed up the code if you're trying to speed things up due to the Global Interpreter Lock

Comment: But while the second function is running, if I run function 1 as a thread, won't it still run at the same time? I mean if function 2 takes 30 minutes for example, and function 1 takes an hour, and while function 2 runs I also run function 1 as a thread, won't I save 30 minutes?

Comment: Create a queue and pass it to `foo` to fill. Create another queue and pass it to `foo2` to fill, and also the first queue to consume. Pass the second queue to `foo3` to consume.

Comment: @NickS. it depends what you're doing, threading isn't a free boost. If you want to use multiple processors, see [**`multiprocessing`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). However, if you're doing a lot of I/O you might be [I/O bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound).

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks Peter, that solved my problem! Feel free to post it as an answer if you want, so that I can mark it - for anyone else that might need help. Thanks again!

Comment: @NickS. no problem, you're welcome. Feel free to write up an answer yourself. Now that you know the answer you might also be able to clarify your question too (c:

Answer (score 0):

After going through the comments of your questions I did a little more searching. I understand what you are looking is some kind of Pipeline pattern. And it seems Python does have something for it. Answer for the qn in the link also talks abotu what @Peterwood said about making use of queues. 
[How to design an async pipeline pattern in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834662/how-to-design-an-async-pipeline-pattern-in-python)